# How to add numerated column for rows

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How in laravel 7 app using eloquent to add numerated column for rows, starting from 1 and next 2... for request like :

```
$forumPosts = ForumPost
            ::getByForumThreadId($forum_thread_id)
            ->orderBy($order_by, $order_direction)
            ->offset($limit_start)
            ->take($forum_posts_per_page)
            ->get()
```

?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add counter and select it:

```
 DB::statement(DB::raw('set @rownum='.$limit_start));

$forumPosts = ForumPost
            ::getByForumThreadId($forum_thread_id)
            ->orderBy($order_by, $order_direction)
            ->offset($limit_start)
            ->take($forum_posts_per_page)
->select('forumPosts.*',DB::raw('@rownum  := @rownum  + 1 AS rownum'))
            ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks! Does it with that I created a new var rownum in this session ?

Comment: I don't know exactly your case, but you can not depend on this column as unchanged key, row number may change for several reason, for example deletion, adding where to the query